# Has vavr io.vavr.API been removed in 1.0.0-alpha-2?

Tags: vavr

I have been investigating the use of the excellent functional library `vavr`

```
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.vavr/vavr
compile group: 'io.vavr', name: 'vavr', version: '0.9.2'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.vavr/vavr-match
compile group: 'io.vavr', name: 'vavr-match', version: '0.9.2'
```

Using this type of example:-

```
int input = 2;
        String output = Match(input).of(Case($(1), "one"), Case($(2), "two"), Case($(3), "three"), Case($(), "?"));

        assertEquals("two", output);
```

using these static imports

```
import static io.vavr.API.$;
import static io.vavr.API.Case;
import static io.vavr.API.Match;
```

However when I upgrade to

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.vavr/vavr
compile group: 'io.vavr', name: 'vavr', version: '1.0.0-alpha-2'
```

I can no longer resolve the `io.vavr.API` imports.

Where have these been refactored to in the most recent version of `vavr`?

Have they been removed altogether?

Comment: Note that the 1.0.0 is very early stage right now. You might want to consider using the 0.9.x line, or better, the 0.10.x line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR Yes, it has been removed from 1.x.x.

Please have a look at this [post](http://blog.vavr.io/fast-forward-to-vavr-1-0/), especially this part:

> We can't change the Java language by ourselves. All features that try
>   to do so, e.g. pattern matching and for comprehensions, will be moved
>   to a separate module vavr-api. Because different Java 9 modules can't
>   export the same package, the package name needs to be changed.
>
> Please note that Java will come up with native pattern matching.
>   Therefore the use of vavr-api is discouraged but it will still be
>   maintained.
>
> All main modules mentioned above (excluding vavr-api and the co-module
>   vavr-match) will be available as one big bundle, called
>   vavr-all-in-one.

I'm not up-to-date with the status of current work, however it will be no longer available in the core module.

Comment: this means I cannot use vavr in my android projects as AFAIK android has only just managed to support Java 8. With the push on Kotlin I'd expect google to soon announce that they will stop supporting java development of Android Apps :(

Answer (score 2):

io.vavr.API will still be part of Vavr 1.0, however, the contents most probably will be changed.

The alpha-* versions are increments. I will provide new features step-by-step in order to make them available for testing purposes.

I see that this is a bit confusing because my users expect more complete contents of an alpha version. Currently I'm working on that issue.

(Disclaimer: I'm the author of Vavr)

Comment: Thank you for the kind words :)